# Sequence of isometries converging to an isometry?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $M$ be a compact metric space, and let $(i_n)$ be a sequence of isometries $i_n: M \rightarrow M$. Prove that there exists a subsequence $i_{n_k}$ that converges to an isometry $i$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm a bit stuck on this; I have tried showing that the space of isometries is compact, but don't know if this is an accurate statement, nor do I know how to show it. I also know that all isometries are continuous, but I don't know how this factors into a solution for a problem, if at all.

I figure that I can also show that $(i_n)$ is equicontinuous, and since $M$ is compact (thus closed), we can somehow use Arzela-Ascoli to show that $(i_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, if $(i_n)$ is equicontinuous, then, since your space is compact Hausdorff , $(i_n)$ is compact and then your result follows.

Comment: Yeah, I get that much, but I'm having trouble showing that $(i_n)$ is equicontinuous...

Answer (score 1):

Since, for each $n$, $i_n$ is an isometry, $||i_n(x) - i_n(y)|| = ||i_n (x - y)|| = ||x - y||$, hence picking $\delta = \epsilon$ you have your equicontinuity. Now, just note that your space $M$ is  Hausdorff compact and a metric space, and that $\{i_n\}$ is closed and pointwise compact, therefore $\{i_n\}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right, you can use Arzelà-Ascoli for this, you only need to show that $\left\{ i_{n}\right\} _{n\in \mathbb{N} }$ is bounded and equinocontinuous.

Boundedness comes easily since $M$ is compact it is bounded and each $i_{n}$ send $M$ to $M$ thus $$\left| i_{n}\left( p\right) \right| \leq diam\left( M\right) $$ for all $p\in M$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

To show equinocontinuity let $\varepsilon  > 0$ and $\delta  < \varepsilon $. So if $p,q\in M\wedge d\left( p,q\right)  < \delta \wedge n\in \mathbb{N} $ then $$d\left( i_{n}\left( p\right) ,i_{n}\left( q\right) \right) =d\left( p,q\right)  < \delta  < \varepsilon $$.